# Binary Search not working when it should be

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, binary-search

I have a binary search that searches a list from a user given input of an email. I get no errors and I get no output from it. I can't see where its going wrong?

```
def BubbleSort(logindata):
    NoSwaps = 1
    N = len(logindata)
    logindata = list(logindata)
    while NoSwaps == 1:
        Count = 1
        NoSwaps = 0
        for Count in range(N-1):
            if logindata[Count] > logindata[Count+1]:
                temp = logindata[Count]
                logindata[Count] = logindata[Count+1]
                logindata[Count+1]=temp
                NoSwaps=1
    return tuple(logindata)

def BinarySearch(logindata,ItemSought):
    First=0
    Last=len(logindata)-1
    ItemFound = False
    SearchFailed = False
    while ItemFound == False or SearchFailed == False:
        Midpoint = (First + Last) // 2
        if logindata[Midpoint] == ItemSought:
            print("Item Found")
            ItemFound = True
            print("Item Found")
            break

        elif logindata[Midpoint][0] > ItemSought:
            Last = Midpoint - 1

        else:
            First = Midpoint + 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logindata=["tom@gmail.com","Password1"],["harry@gmail.com","Password2"],["jake@gmail.com","Password3"]
    logindata=BubbleSort(logindata)
    print(logindata)
    ItemSought=input("Enter username")
    BinarySearch(logindata,ItemSought)
```

Comment: Hah, the syntax highlighter is all confused ..   Classes! ClassesEverywhere!

Comment: One more hint: don't use first and last index, use first and one-past-last pair. So Last = len(logindata) - 1 will become Last = len(logindata). It simplifies a lot of limit cases (like empty input, your code can't handle it now).

Answer (score 2):

In

```
if logindata[Midpoint] == ItemSought:
```

you compare list with a string. So I think you need

```
 if logindata[Midpoint][0] == ItemSought:
```

Answer (score 1):

You never terminate the search.  If the item isn't in the list, you get to a stable midpoint and loop infinitely.  If you do find the item, you loop infinitely on *that* (see Yehven's answer).

I traced it with the additions you see here:

```
SearchFailed = False
iter = 0
while iter < 10 and (ItemFound == False or SearchFailed == False):
    iter += 1
    Midpoint = (First + Last) // 2
    print (First, Midpoint, Last, ItemSought)
    if logindata[Midpoint] == ItemSought:
```

Note that you don't ever change **SearchFailed**.  For instance, when I search for "harry", the loop hits a stable infinite point at (0, -1, -2) for First, Middle, Last.

Is that enough of a hint to let you fix it yourself?